# Template template parameters - extension to std::array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I have a question about template template parameters:

Let's consider the following class:

```
template<typename T, template<class, class=std::allocator<T> > class UnderlyingContainerType = std::vector>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    T Value1;
    T Value2;
    UnderlyingContainerType<T> Container;

    MyContainer() {}

    /* methods implementation goes here */
};
```

In this example, MyContainer is a container chat uses an underlying STL-compatible container to do whatever stuff.

Declaring the underlying container type as a template template parameters, instead of a regular template argument, allows handy usage of the class MyContainer, such as:

```
    MyContainer<int> MCV; //implicitly using vector
    MyContainer<int, std::list> MCL; //no need to write std::list<int> thanks to the 
                                     //template template parameters
```

Now, while this would work perfectly with most of the STL-container, such as std::vector, std::deque, std::list, and so forth, it would not work, for example, with std::array provided in c++11.

The reason is that std::array has a different signature of template parameters than vector. Specifically, they are:

```
std::vector<class T, class allocator = std::allocator<T> >
std::array<class T, int N>
```

MY question is if there is a way to generalize the class MyContainer, so that the underlying container can be std::array as well.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Uh, where do you expect to get the size from if it's an array?

Comment: Is your container fixed length or variable length?  If it is variable length, how would std::array fit in it?  Do you understand the length of std::array is required to be known at compile time?

Comment: @ icando: Yes, I know it. Because mycontainer never modify the size of the container, I would like to use it with an array if the size is known at compile time, or with a vector if the size must be specified at run time (e.g. by reading a configuration file). In both cases the size is set once forever, therefore both std::vector and std::array would be compatible with MyClass. I was looking for a way to implement both without code duplication

Comment: It would increase your odds of getting a concrete answer if you show how you plan to differentiate the cases where you know the size at compile-time vs those where you only get it at runtime. For example, if you are passing a constant expression with the size when it's known at compile-time, you could specialize your class or perhaps a helper construct based on it.

Answer (score 3):

The commonality between the interfaces of `vector` and `array` are limited to the element type. Your container should reflect that:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class underlying_container>
struct container
{
    underlying_container<T> storage;
};
```

Usage now requires a tiny trick:

```
template<typename T> using vec = vector<T>;
template<typename T> using arr2 = array<T, 2>;
```

Note that `vec`, unlike `vector`, has a fixed allocator and that `arr2`, unlike `array`, has a fixed size.

Usage is now simple:

```
container<int, vec> a;
container<double, arr2> b;
```

[See the example in action.](https://ideone.com/Uqo377)

Alternatively, if you prefer to match up the interface to that used by vector, just add a template alias for `array` that instantiates the size and adds an unused type parameter:

```
template<typename T, typename> using arr2 = array<T, 2>;
```

[See it in action.](https://ideone.com/iOyupe)

Comment: I like your idea of using aliases. I have slightly modified the code you proposed me. In your version the class T could be theoretically be assigned to any type, here I force it to be the right one. However, it does not compile when I try to use aliases (of course compile with -std=c++11). How can I add the code in the comments to show you what my problem is?

Comment: @Giuseppe Comments are not intended for large amounts of code. If you feel that it should truly be a comment, consider dropping a full example to such a service like ideone.com or pastebin.com and just adding the link to the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to achieve exactly, what you want. But if you don't require the ability to write `MyContainer<int> MCV;` you could use

```
template<class UnderlyingContainerType, class T = typename UnderlyingContainerType::value_type>
class MyContainer
{
public:
    T Value1;
    T Value2;
    UnderlyingContainerType Container;

    MyContainer() {}

    /* methods implementation goes here */
};


int main() {
    MyContainer<std::vector<int>> MCV{};
    MyContainer<std::array<int, 5>> MCA{};
}
```

Which is not more to type than `MyContainer<int, std::vector> MCV;`
Also you can of course still add an alias for your vector based version:

```
template<class T>
using MyContainerV = MyContainer < std::vector<T> > ;
```

Comment: Please don't claim something isn't possible in C++ unless you are pretty certain.  :)  C++ is a big language.

Comment: @Yakk: Are you saying that you know its possible or just that my claim is too bold without a "formal proof"?

Comment: well, see @gha.st 's answer, which does pass an `array` to `MyContainer` via a template alias.  Variations on that could even allow passing a traits type that lets the `MyContainer` consume them uniformly.  It is impossible to have a parameter accept both a `template<class, size_t>class` and a `template<class, class>class`, but the OP didn't precisely ask for that: the OP just asked to use an underlying `array` in `MyContainer`.

Comment: @Yakk: You are right, I interpreted too much into the question. I already changed my statement.